# Basic trouble with Python lists in Numba; what's going on?

Tags: python, list, numba

I'm a beginner to Numba. For the life in me I can't get a Numba function to manipulate a simple list.
Heck, I can't even figure out how to specify the signature.

Here's the example. What's wrong? (What's a "reflected list"?) And how do I fix it?

```
from numba import *
from numba.types import *

@jit(List(int64)(List(int64)), nopython=True)
def foo(a): a[0] += a[0]; return a

foo([1])
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", in <module>
    foo([1])
  File "numba\dispatcher.py", line 219, in _explain_matching_error
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) reflected list(int64)
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're specifying a signature at all?

Comment: @user2357112: Yes, I want to learn how to do it in places where it can't auto-infer.

Comment: As far as my Google skills indicate, a "reflected" list is [one where changes to the list inside a JITted function will be visible (reflected) in the list after the function executes](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1444). This is treated as a distinct type from a regular list, for reasons I do not know. You've told Numba your function should take a non-reflected list, but it needs to take a reflected list, by passing `reflected=True` to the inner `List` call. It may also need to return a reflected list.

Comment: I am not a Numba user, I do not have a Numba install to test on, and it is way past my bedtime. I don't know if I got that right.

Comment: @user2357112: Ooh, I think you got it! I searched a while but didn't manage to find any info on the meaning of "reflected" list! Please post it as an answer when you get the chance :) I'm running into a different problem now but I'll post it as a separate question, thanks!

Comment: I'll do it in the morning, if someone with actual Numba expertise doesn't come along first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any documentation on the subject, but from the things that came up when I [Googled the topic](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1444) and [dug through the source code](https://github.com/numba/numba/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reflected&type=), a "reflected" list is one where changes to the list have to be visible (reflected) in Python after a JITted function is done with it. Reflected lists are treated as a different type from non-reflected lists in the Numba type system, for reasons I do not know. The concept may be specific to nopython mode; I'm not sure, and I can't test it.

You've declared that your function takes a non-reflected list, but it needs to take a reflected list. You need to add `reflected=True` to the inner `List(int64)` call, and possibly the outer one as well.