# Problem with reflected list signature in numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to use Ahead-of-Time compilation on one of my functions and because of that I need to provide the signatures for the function. When I use `numba.typeof()` I get back `reflected list(array(float64, 2d, A))` for one of my variables. I've looked at this thread [Basic trouble with Python lists in Numba; what's going on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166418/basic-trouble-with-python-lists-in-numba-whats-going-on) to try and figure out the signature, but I've been running into errors.

Before trying to get AOT compilation to work I'm just trying to get @njit to work with signatures.

I've tried:

```
@njit(float64[:,:,:](int32, list(float64), float64[:,:,:]), reflected=True)
```

How can I fix my signature so it works? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the signature of your `list` correctly. This means solving a few issues in your code:

- `reflected=True` must be an argument of your call of the `List` type class
- I don't know how and where you import `list`. If you did not import it, it is not a numba type. If you did import something as `list`, you overwrote the python builtins module `list`. You should **NEVER** do this. So instead of list I'd write `nb.types.List(...)`, supposing that you import numba with `import numba as nb`. If you imported numba with `from numba import *`: This is another thing you should avoid at all costs.
- the `float64` type which is stored in your list needs to be specified more precisely. You have an array of type `array(float64, 2d, A)` in your reflected list. This means your list signature needs to contain exactly this array type. In this case this will look like: `nb.float64[:, :]`. For other memory layouts like C- or F-, take a look at [this post](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/2789#issuecomment-415010514).

So your resulting signature will look like this:

```
@nb.njit(nb.float64[:, :, :](nb.int32, nb.types.List(nb.float64[:, :], reflected=True), nb.float64[:, :, :]))
```

Again assuming that you import numba with `import numba as nb` and that your array is of the type `array(float64, 2d, A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Often, another option to make the code work is to switch from lists to numpy arrays.

(I know, this was not the question, but could help people...)